# Server 2008 TS Licensing Diagnosis has not discovered any license servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server

I have installed Terminal Services and Terminal Services Licensing on a 2008 SP2 Domain Controller.  I have an Open License for Terminal Services and I have successfully Activated the Licensing server and all looks good in the TS Licensing Manager.  TS Cal Availability is Available and when I log users on TS Cals In Use shows the correct figure.  The Server is also showing as Activated.

However, if I open Server Manager, Expand Roles, Terminal Services, Terminal Services Configuration and click on Licensing Diagnosis I get the following warning:

The Terminal Server is within its grace period, but the terminal server has not discovered any license servers.

I have tried changing License Server Discovery Mode from Automatic to the FQDN of the server.  When I click Check Names I get a message stating it is a valid license server, however the warning message still remains.  Even after a reboot it is still there.

I have also tried uninstalling Terminal Services and TS Licensing and reinstalling but I still get the same message.  I cannot see anything obvious in the event viewer.  Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/4fa27bdd-0b9e-440f-a7c7-146a7484a028

Answer (score 1):

This may sound silly but I know this has caused panics in my environments before. Make sure you are logged into the terminal server as a domain user with proper privs (or launch the mmc as a domain user). The licensing diagnosis will not complete the queries properly if logged in using a local account on the TS box.

Comment: I am logging on as a domain admin (the server is a DC).

Answer (score 1):

Have you done [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737307%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have just tried that and the server is correctly listed.  This is definitely a strange one.